# React only partially re-renders a stateless component after input data changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-18

**Edit - as question not answered yet**:
Minimal reproducable example (I am a beginner programmer - I don't know how to add nextjs snippets to codepen or similar - but this runs on my local host and reproduces the error.):

```
'use client';

import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const generateData = (keywords: string[] = ['test', 'stack']) => {
  const newData = [];
  const minChunk = 2;
  const maxChunk = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
    const word = keywords[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < keywords.length; j += 1) {
      if (i !== j) {
        const nextWord = keywords[j];
        for (let k = minChunk; k < maxChunk + 1; k += 1) {
          const firstChunk = word.slice(0, k);
          for (let l = minChunk; l < maxChunk + 1; l += 1) {
            const nextChunk = nextWord.slice(-l);
            const newItem = firstChunk + nextChunk;
            newData.push(newItem);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return newData;
};

export default function ParentComponent({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: {
    p: string;
  };
}) {
  const keyword = searchParams.p ?? '';
  const keywordArray = keyword.split(',');
  const { replace } = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  if (keywordArray[keywordArray.length - 1] === '') {
    keywordArray.pop();
  }

  const data = generateData(keywordArray);

  function handleChange(term: string, paramLetter: string) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (term) {
      params.set(paramLetter, term);
    } else {
      params.delete(paramLetter);
    }

    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-32">
      <input
        id="keyword"
        placeholder="Keyword"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value.split(' ').join(','), 'p')}
      />

      <h1>Results: </h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Initial Post:**

I have the following example react (v18.2) code which works completely fine and as expected -> once p in the searchParams changes, the list in MyComponent is replaced with fresh data. P changes with the users' keystrokes in an input field.

```
const ParentComponent = ({ searchParams }) => {
  const generateData = (searchParams) => {
    const { p } = searchParams;
    const newData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const newItem = p + i.toString();
      newData.push(newItem);
    }

    return newData;
  };

  const data = generateData(searchParams);

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => (
  <ul>
    {data.map(item => (
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

However, in my actual component, the generateData function, consists of 4 for-loops to create the data. The 4 for-loops loop for a maximum of (5 options * 4 options * 2 options * 2 options =) 80 times in total to generate the needed data, e.g. as following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 const newItem = p + i.toString()
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   newItem += j.toString()
    for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
     newItem += k.toString()
      for (let l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
       newItem += l.toString()
       newData.push(newItem);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My Problem**:

- If I only add the second for-loop (or the third or the fourth or all of them combined) to my code, the list in MyComponent is NOT replaced with the new data BUT it keeps all historic data and appends all new data to the list.

**Expected Behaviour**:

- The list in MyComponent should replace the old data once new data comes in and not append the new data to the list.

**What I tried**:

- Removing the for-loops (it works fine with 1 for-loop and breaks after adding a second)
- Reducing the number of options in the for-loops (didn't help)
- Introducing useState in the parent (didn't help)
- Moving the generateData function outside of the component (didn't help)
- Asking ChatGPT (didn't help - although it suggested that it might be perfomance issues in the generateData function. I can imagine that but not with this small amount of loops - correct?)

Comment: *MyComponent is NOT replaced with the new data* The word "replaced" is throwing me off here. I don't see state anywhere that would cause your components to ever re-render. So I would never expect anything to be replaced, it would calculate it once and that would be the end. I'm wondering if HMR from NextJS is having an effect here? If not, could you please explain what I'm missing about replacing data?

Comment: The component does include an input field (which is not shown). Any input triggers a handleChange function which uses useRouter -> 'replace' to add the params (here the user input as p) to the url. The ParentComponent gets new searchParams and re-renders. I can add the input field if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `+=` operation on a const because it's a re-assignment. This is causing an error and my assumption is that your HMR setup is causing it to look like the problem is something else.

Aside from that,  your loop works as expected.

```js
const ParentComponent = ({ searchParams }) => {
  const generateData = (searchParams) => {
    const { p } = searchParams;
    const newData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     let newItem = p + i.toString();
      for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       newItem += j.toString();
        for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
         newItem += k.toString();
          for (let l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
           newItem += l.toString();
           newData.push(newItem);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return newData;
  };

  const data = generateData(searchParams);

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => (
  <ul>
    {data.map(item => (
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent searchParams={{ p: 'test' }} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Initially the code runs perfect with my example as well. But when I know change the input p via the input field (not shown in example), e.g. deleting 'test' one character after another and write 'stack' into the inputfield. The result list as you generated STAYS and all the results using the word 'stack' apend to the list.

Comment: @Tilka you need to provide a [mcve] then if this is not sufficient to answer your question. The code you provided has a problem, this answer solves it. We can't solve problems that are not reproducible in the question

Comment: I edited my post with a minimal reproducible example. Thanks a lot for your help.